# netbeans + hibernate for java swing application

Tags: hibernate, swing, jpa, netbeans, persistence

im developing a java swing app and i would use hibernate for persistance.
Im totally new in jpa, hibernate and ORM in general.

Im follow [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html) tutorial, its easy but the problem is the java class that descrive a table in db are made from the table with reverse enginering.

I want do the opposite process: i want make db table from the java class.

The question is, how can i do this with netbeans? There are some tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is more usual to reverse engineer the database to generate the java class.

If you want to generate the database from the java class, you can generate a DDL for each hibernate object like this :

> AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
>   config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
>   config.configure();
>   new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

With these parameters for the method create :
*create(boolean script, boolean export)*

script - print the DDL to the console
export - export the script to the database